# Trying to redirect user to newly created post using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails controller that should redirect me to a newly created post:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:date, :rationale))
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

the view for the show method is:

```
<%= @post.inspect %>
```

The following test passes:

```
it 'can be created from new form' do
      visit new_post_path
      fill_in 'post[date]', with: Date.today
      fill_in 'post[rationale]', with: "Some rationale"
      click_on "Save"
      expect(page).to have_content("Some rationale")
  end
```

however when I run through the browser, the redirect only goes to the index /posts

**Expected Behaviour:** The user should be redircted to the view show and see the newly created post

If I hard code the id into the redirect I can see the newly created post

Comment: Most likely the post wasn't saved so it's redirecting to nil id. `@post.save!` will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can find route using this, **rails routes** then find the routes with the **posts** id, either you want to use prefix/ URI pattern.
in this case, seems like you're using show.
then you can use redirect_to '/post/:id/show' for URI pattern, the id should be @post.id